# How to burn Cardano token after the 'invalid after' passes?

Tags: cardano-cli, native-assets, minting, token

My token policy script is:

```
all: 
    [
        {
           invalidAfter: 40951072
        },
        {
           pubKey: "36ed345d252a242ad67072db79e5736866fa58ebe3fd782739208ef6"
        }
    ]
```

Since the slot already passes it looks like I can't burn tokens by cardano-cli 'mint' anymore. The error I get is:

**Command failed: transaction submit  Error: Error while submitting tx: ShelleyTxValidationError ShelleyBasedEraAlonzo (ApplyTxError [UtxowFailure (WrappedShelleyEraFailure (ScriptWitnessNotValidatingUTXOW (fromList [ScriptHash "6c6d152385ada4cc7606a31090ac37ac267b0b5e2e37ecaf6b47d146"])))])**

I wonder is there any other 'best practice' to burn the token?

Answer (score 2):

As Isaac stated, transaction with this policy is not possible anymore. But that does not mean it is not possible to publicly make assets unavailable. There is a great post on the Cardano form that goes in-depth on different types of burning methods [[1](https://forum.cardano.org/t/proof-of-burn-smart-contract/79540/27)]. Note that these tokens send to such addresses still exists but can't be transferred anymore by anyone.

Answer (score 1):

You could send it to a wallet you control then destroy any record of your credentials :)

Comment: It does not answer the case since I need to 'destroy' them publically. So anyone could be sure that it was burned.

Comment: It's impossible to get the policy script to validate since the validity interval has passed. There is actually no way to burn the token because Cardano was designed that way. Take a video of yourself transferring it to a hardware wallet then smashing it with a hammer :)